# how do I restart the program if the input is = no in python

Tags: python

when the input is =no when asking if the statement is correct, It ends the program, but I want it to restart the program from the beginning, this is in python on vs code

```py
while True:
    product = input("Enter product name: ")
    price = float(input("What is the price of the product: "))
    print(f'''You want to save towards purchasing {product.title()} which costs {price} dollars(Can)''')

    correct = input ("Is this correct, Yes or No: ")
        
    if correct == "no":
        print("Re-enter correct data")

    if correct == "yes":
        
        add_a_second_product = input("would you like to add a second product, Yes or No: ")

        if add_a_second_product == "no":
            current_saved = float(input("How much money do you currently have saved: "))
            print(f'''You need {round(price-current_saved,2)} more dollars''')
            
            if current_saved >= price:
                print(f'''you have {current_saved} dollars which is enough to purchase {product} for {price}$''')
    

        if add_a_second_product == "yes":
            product2 = input("Enter second product name: ")
            price2 = float(input("What is the price of the second product: "))
            print(f'''You want to save towards purchasing {product.title()} and {product2.title()} which costs {round(price+price2,2)} dollars(Can)''')

            correct2 = input ("is this correct, Yes or No: ")
            if correct2 == "no":
                print("Re-enter correct data")

            if correct2 == "yes":
                current_saved2 = float(input("How much do you currently have saved: "))
                print(f'''You need {round(price+price2-current_saved2,2)} more dollars''')
    

            if current_saved2 >= price:
                print(f'''you have {current_saved2} dollars which is enough to purchase {product} for {price}$''')
            
            if current_saved2-price >= price2:
                print(f'''you have {current_saved2} dollars which is enough to purchase {product2} for {price2}$''')
    exit()
```

I tried using a break command in it but that just stopped the whole program, I tried using a continue and break together but the continue just reran the try again print, I could have used those commands wrong but I do not know as I am only about 1 week into learning python.

Comment: _I tried using a continue and break together_ Saying "I tried this" or "I tried that" is not very helpful.  A _description_ of the code is not enough, because we would have to guess exactly what you meant.  We need to see the **actual** code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to the start of the `while` as soon as `print("Re-enter correct data")`

```
...
    if correct == "no":
        print("Re-enter correct data")
        continue    
    if correct == "yes":
...
```